# Find the dimensions of a cylindrical can that will minimize the cost of the material

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

> A cylindrical can is to be made to hold 1 L of oil. Find the dimensions
>   that will minimize the cost of the metal to manufacture the can.

This is a standard calculus problem.

The volume of the cylinder is:

`V == π r^2 h`

The area of the cylinder is:

`A[r_] := 2 π r^2 + 2 π r h /. h -> V/(π r^2)`

Find `r` when the slope of the area is zero:

```
Reduce[A'[r] == 0]
```

Result:

```
(r == -(-(1/(2 π)))^(1/3) V^(1/3) || 
   r == V^(1/3)/(2 π)^(1/3) || 
   r == ((-1)^(2/3) V^(1/3))/(2 π)^(1/3)) && r != 0
```

As you can see, when I defined `A[r]`, I replaced `h` with an expression produced by solving the volume equation for `h`.

My question is, is there a way to express the problem in terms of Reduce and a set of equations, without the manual solving for `h`?

I.e. something along the lines of:

```
A[r_] := 2 π r^2 + 2 π r h

Reduce[{A'[r] == 0, V == π r^2 h}]
```

Of course, that doesn't yield the correct answer because `A'[r]` doesn't treat `h` as being in terms of `r`.

Comment: Why not use `Minimize[{2 Pi r^2 + 2 Pi r h, Pi r^2 h == 1/1000, r > 0, h > 0}, {r, h}]`?

Comment: @J.M. Wasn't familiar with `Minimize`... Thanks for the suggestion! However, is there a way to get the answer not in terms of `Root`?

Comment: @J.M. I'm still curious as to how to solve it with `Reduce`. I added an answer which takes the approach I was looking for, but uses a rewrite kludge.

Comment: "However, is there a way to get the answer not in terms of `Root[]`?" - yes, use `ToRadicals[]`; it will work here since it is the root of a cubic polynomial.

Comment: "I'm still curious as to how to solve it with `Reduce[]`." - `Reduce[D[2 Pi r^2 + 2 Pi r h /. First[Solve[Pi r^2 h == 1/1000, h]], r] == 0 && r > 0, r]`

Comment: It seems there is a bug in `ToRadicals`. Try `ToRadicals[ Root[1000 Pi #^3 - 15 (2 Pi)^(1/3) # + 1 &, 2]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested, here is a method that uses `Reduce[]`:

```
Reduce[Dt[2 Pi r^2 + 2 Pi r h, r] == 0 && Pi r^2 h == 1/1000 && Positive[r], {r, h}]
```

I'd still prefer using `Minimize[]`, though.

Comment: Aha... I had been using `D` (partial derivative) necessitating the expression of `h` in terms of `r`. I see that `Dt` takes care of this. Thanks again J.M.!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found one approach:

```
A[r_] := 2 \[Pi] r^2 + 2 \[Pi] r h
V[r_] := \[Pi] r^2 h
Reduce[{Dt[A[r], r] == 0, V[r] == 1, r > 0}]
```

Result:

```
r == 1/(2 \[Pi])^(1/3) && h == 2^(2/3)/\[Pi]^(1/3)
```